# adding a delay to page refresh so success message is displayed longer

Tags: jquery, settimeout, reload

I have a form that is done in a lightbox, once it is submitted successfully it displays a success message, and will then reload the page.  how do I delay the page reload so the user has some time to see the message? with the code below, the delay happens once the button is hit and it gets hung up and displays a "mail:Could not instantiate mail function."

```
if(data.result == 'success')
    {   
        $('form#car-inquiry').siblings('#form-welcome').hide();
        $('form#car-inquiry').hide();
        $('#success_message').show();
        $('#error_message').hide();
        setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload(true);}, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: without this setTimeout are you still getting error " mail:Could not instantiate mail function " ?

Comment: no, without the set timeout and just doing the location.reload function without a timeout, it works fine. but then end user really doesn't see success message so don't want to create confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this in your script

```
if(data.result == 'success')
 {   
  setTimeout(function () {
     $('form#car-inquiry').siblings('#form-welcome').hide();
     $('form#car-inquiry').hide();
     $('#success_message').show();
     $('#error_message').hide();
             }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload(true);
             }, 1500);
 }
```

Comment: Happy to help.happy coding!!